# помогите найти ошибку в коде на питоне

Tags: python

Решала такую задачу:У Васи есть прямоугольное поле, которое состоит из 2
строк и n
столбцов. Каждая ячейка имеет цвет: красный, зелёный или синий.

У Васи дальтонизм и он не отличает зелёный цвет от синего. Определите, одинаково ли Вася видит первую и вторую строку поля? Входные данные:

```
6
2
RG
RB
4
GRBG
GBGB
5
GGGGG
BBBBB
7
BBBBBBB
RRRRRRR
8
RGBRRGBR
RGGRRBGR
1
G
G
```

выходные данные:

```
YES
NO
YES
NO
YES
YES
```

написала по этой задаче код, вроде все в порядке, но код на тесты выводит неверные ответы. Помогите пожалуйста!!!
мой код:

```
n=int(input())
ans=[]
for i in range(n):
    q=int(input())
    l1=list(map(str, input().split(" ")))
    l2=list(map(str, input().split(" ")))
    w=11
    for j in range(len(l1)):
        if w==11:
            if (l1[j]=="R" and l2[j]!="R") or (l1[j]!="R" and l2[j]=="R"):
                w=12 
            if not ((l1[j]=="R" and l2[j]!="R") or (l1[j]!="R" and l2[j]=="R")) and w==11 and j==len(l1)-1:
                ans.append("YES")
                w=11
            if not ((l1[j]=="R" and l2[j]!="R") or (l1[j]!="R" and l2[j]=="R")) and w==11 and not (j==len(l1)-1):
                w=11
        if w!=11:
            ans.append("NO")
for s in range(len(ans)):
    print(ans[s])
```

переписывала много раз, уже почти отчаялась найти ошибку, очень прошу о помощи

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответы такие же как и у вас в примере, по тому что G=B
Возможно вы имели ввиду что-то другое, если да дайте примеры правильных ответов. Так же не понимаю зачем вам так много кода и лишние переменные, по возможности объясните.

```
ans=[]
n=int(input())
for iter in range(n):
    l1=input('Line 1:').replace('G', 'B')
    l2=input('Line 2:').replace('G', 'B')

    if l1 == l2:
        ans.append("YES")
    else:
        ans.append("NO")
for s in range(len(ans)):
    print(ans[s])
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: спасибо огромное вам, просто моя идея была в том, чтобы сравнивать каждую пару элементов по индексу

Answer (score 0):

```
# принимаем количество тестов
n = int(input())

# создаем пустой список для хранения ответов
ans = []

# для каждого теста
for i in range(n):
    # принимаем количество элементов и два списка
    q = int(input())
    l1 = list(map(str, input().split(" ")))
    l2 = list(map(str, input().split(" ")))

    # инициализируем переменную w
    w = 11

    # для каждого элемента в списках
    for j in range(len(l1)):
        # если w равна 11
        if w == 11:
            # если l1[j] равна "R" и l2[j] не равна "R", или наоборот
            if (l1[j] == "R" and l2[j] != "R") or (l1[j] != "R" and l2[j] == "R"):
                # устанавливаем w в 12
                w = 12
            # если l1[j] и l2[j] не содержат "R" и w равна 11 и это последний элемент
            elif not ((l1[j] == "R" and l2[j] != "R") or (l1[j] != "R" and l2[j] == "R")) and w == 11 and j == len(l1) - 1:
                # добавляем "YES" в список ответов и устанавливаем w в 11
                ans.append("YES")
                w = 11
            # если l1[j] и l2[j] не содержат "R" и w равна 11 и это не последний элемент
            elif not ((l1[j] == "R" and l2[j] != "R") or (l1[j] != "R" and l2[j] == "R")) and w == 11 and not (j == len(l1) - 1):
                # устанавливаем w в 11
                w = 11
        # если w не равна 11
        if w != 11:
            # добавляем "NO" в список ответов
            ans.append("NO")

    # добавляем "YES" или "NO" в список ответов в зависимости от значения w
    if w == 11:
        ans.append("YES")
    else:
        ans.append("NO")

# выводим все ответы
for s in ans:
    print(s)
```

Comment: ваша программа выводит 12 YES...

Comment: почему-то программа не замечает, что в некоторый момент w становится не равно 11